# Asynchronous requests script crashes with too many URLs

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to check a set of URLs for their status code and return all that are of code 4xx or 5xx.
In total I need to check about 12500 URLs and my script works fine for up to about 7000 URLs. Above that the script crashes with ResourceWarning unclosed transport error.

I'm using python-3.6 and aiohttp 3.5.4

Any idea what's causing this?

```
async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        data = response.status
        return url, data


async def bound_fetch(sem, url, session):
    async with sem:
        return await fetch(url, session)


async def check_urls(url_list):
    ''' get status code for all urls and write into dictionary '''

    base_url = <base_url>   
    tasks = []

    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10)

    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for url in url_list:
            full_url = base_url + url
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(sem, full_url.format(), session))
            tasks.append(task)

        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        results_dict = defaultdict(list)
        for res in results:
            if res[1] != 200 and res[1] != 301 and res[1] != 302:
                print(f'ERROR {str(res[1])} {res[0]}')
                results_dict[res[1]].append(res[0])

        print(f'URLs checked, found {str(len(results_dict))} errors')


''' main function'''
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.set_debug(True)
warnings.simplefilter('always', ResourceWarning)
future = asyncio.ensure_future(check_urls(list_of_urls))
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

Comment: Can u specify exact error u are getting?

Comment: Excep the following line, there's nothing in the log file and script doesn't seem to finish: /usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/sslproto.py:334: ResourceWarning: unclosed transport <asyncio.sslproto._SSLProtocolTransport object at 0x7f8a0c4d1860>

Comment: You need to add await asyncio.sleep(0)  just before loop closing -- warning disappears.
Check this link for further clarification. 
https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/1115
Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try that.

Comment: Still crashing, last line of log: aiohttp.client_exceptions.ServerDisconnectedError: None. Could I run into a server issue or some sort of limit? Requests are run against an nginx webserver with laravel

Comment: Found the error and it's a tiny bit embarassing. We have a cronjob that runs every hour and reloads nginx. Apparently reloading nginx kills the session from aiohttp. Not a script related error, thanks for your help!